# How to reduce the overhead when there are a lot of checking per elements in lists (From O(n2) to O(n))

Tags: dart

I have a class(lets call it Path) that contain a list of points of locations.

However, only Path that contains points **near my current location is my interests**. So I may need to iterate the list of points to see if this path is suitable.

As you can see, per checking is quite heavy, even if there are only few points within a path. **O(n)**

The problem got worse when I get a pile of path to check. So there could be more than one path suit my interest. **(O(n2))**

So, I would like to check if there is faster way to reduce the overhead. I have created some mock data in  program to illustrate the idea. (given that data is from no sql)

Below is my psudo code for only checking one path

```
class Path{

Path({this.PointOfInterests});

List<PointOfInterest> PointOfInterests

}

class PointOfInterest{

PointOfInterest({this.lat, this.lng});

double lat; 

double lng; 

double calculateDistance(PointOfInterest in){
    return root  (  square((in.lat - this.lat)) + square((in.lng - this.lng)) ) 
}

} 

void main(){


List<PointOfInterest> PointOfInterests = {};
POI1 = new PointOfInterest(lat : 22.24970405555096, lng: 114.1545153839728);
POI2 = new PointOfInterest(lat : 22.24970405555096, lng: 114.1545153839728);

PointOfInterests.add(POI1);
PointOfInterests.add(POI2);
Path path = Path({PointOfInterests}); 

final double rangeToBeConsideredAsNearby = 50; 

//I would like to check if path contain POI which location is within my current region 

PointOfInterest myCurrent = PointOfInterest(lat : 22.247636119175315, lng: 114.15919047431217);

boolean IsWithInMyRegion = IsItContainPOINearbyCurentLocation(myCurrent,path); 
  
print(IsWithInMyRegion); 


IsItContainPOINearbyCurentLocation(PointOfInterest myCurrent,Path path){

//looping the list of path to check the distance one by one

for(int i = 0; i<path.PointOfInterests.length ;i++) {

    // check each point of interest in the path
    if (myCurrent.calculateDistance(path.PointOfInterests[i]) <= rangeToBeConsideredAsNearby) {
      return true
    }
    
    return false
}

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly no easier way to check whether a path, which is just a list of points, contains a point which satisfies something, than checking each point.

If you omit checking any point, that point might be the one satisfying the test, and then the result is wrong.

What you might be able to do is to precompute some "summary" information about the path, and then reuse that later for multiple checks.
Say, for each path, you compute a bounding shape (a rectangle would be simplest, just remember the minimum and maximum for each coordinate), then you check first whether your current position is close to that rectangle. If not, you can ignore the entire path. If so, you'll still have to check each point.

If you only do one check on each path, that might not be faster than just checking each point first, but if you do multiple checks on the same path, the summary computation can be amortized.

Also, if the check on each point is very expensive, doing two runs over the path can still be faster on average, if the first run does something cheaper and less precise, but which can still disqualify a large percentage of paths which would have failed the more expensive check.
That is, even if you compute the boundary rectangle each time, it might be cheap enough compared to checking all the points that it's worth it.
However, it does mean looking at all the elements, even if an early one of them alone would be enough to fail the expensive test.

To avoid that, you can also try to make the check on individual elements cheaper *on average*.

Here you compute the distance as `sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2), pow(y2 - y1, 2))`.
The most expensive part of that is `sqrt`, and it's not needed if all you do to the result is to compare it to a number: `dist <= x` is the same as `distSquared <= x*x`.
Look for optimizations like that.

If you want to avoid the multiplications too, you can start out with a simpler check, like whether *either* direction is already too far away.

```dart
/// Checks whether [p1] is within [dist] distance of [p2].
///
/// The [distSquared] must be `dist * dist`.
/// The [distSqrt] must be `sqrt(dist)`.
bool withinDist(Point p1, Point p2, num dist, num distSquared, num distSqrt) {
  // True if p1 is within a circle with radius dist from p2.
  var dx = (p2.x - p1.x).abs();
  var dy = (p2.y - p1.y).abs();
  // Bail out early if outside a square circumscribing the circle around p2.
  if (dy > dist || dx > dist) return false;
  // Bail out early if inside a square inscribed inside the circle around p2.
  if (dy <= distSqrt && dx <= distSqrt) return true;
  // Properly compute whether inside a `dist` radius circle.
  return dx * dx + dy * dy <= distSquared;
}
```

In short, if you can't avoid looking at all the elements, either:

- Look at them ahead of time and compute a summary which might allow you to skip the entire path, and reduce the needs for the more precise and expensive check. Or ...
- Optimize the expensive check by providing cheap early answers, and only do the most expensive computations when the cheap check is inconclusive. This may be more expensive if the cheap answer is almost always inconclusive. Tailor it to your data and use-cases.

Comment: Thanks for your precomputing and detailed suggestion. 

1.I come up with an idea to implement precomputing. See if you agree? Even though each Point of Interest basically is a point containing the lag and lng info. But I may add one more information which is to simplify lag and lng as district. Then I index the district. So, when I need to search nearby path, which contain Points near my current position, I just need to take my Location and convert it as district and lookup the index to get my interested path. @Irn

Comment: 2. Could you explain bounding shape (a rectangle would be simplest) what does max,min mean here? I dont quite get how does it help to check if it close enough or not @lrn

Comment: mention again, not sure if I type the notify user correctly @lrn

Comment: If "being near" can be reduced to "being in the same district", then that sound perfectly reasonable.

Comment: For the "bounding rectangle", I was thinking to remember the minimum and maximum lat and lng of the points of a path in the path itself. To see if something is within x distance of a point in the path, you could start by checking `(lat < minlat - x || lat > maxlat + x || lng< minlng - x || lng > maxlng + x). If that is true, then the lat,lng point cannot be within `x` distance of of any point in the path. If it's false, you still have to check the path. You can then do the same again for path segments, to be able to skip checking half a path. Other bounding shapes can also be used.

Comment: oh I got your idea, your are trying to look at some extreme points first. If my current position cant pass through those points (max , min), then I dont even need to proceed to do further check. As it turn out, I can reduce average time of checking. Its kind of divide and conquer approach right, but nothing can be half if my current is really within some distance x when compared to the max/min?